# Unable to Use Google Calendar API Parameters

Tags: javascript, http, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Calendar's API to get calendar event data for a project of mine via HTTP requests (Axios), yet I receive `"API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key."` errors whenever I try to use any of [these](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) parameters. I'm fairly certain my authorization is correct yet am stumped as even Google's reference says that such is optional... Example included below:

`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/.../events?key=...` works fine, something as simple as
`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/.../events?key=...?orderBy=startTime` does not. (Results in the error)

I've tried via different keys and calendars with no luck. Is there any workaround or something I'm missing? Extensive research on stack yielded no help either. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query string starts with ?, subsequent key/value pairs are separated using &